# Using xdocreport, is it possible to read drawings from a docx file?

Tags: java, xdocreport

I need to convert a `docx` to a `pdf`. The following code use the library `xdocreport` and works pretty well.

The problem is for some specific `docx` which contain drawings. They are not visible in the final pdf. I've tested the conversion with the live [demo](http://mytomcatapp-opensagres.rhcloud.com/rest-service-converter/) avaible from the github and I've the same problem.

So I'm wondering, is this possible, or do I need to use an other library ? Which one ? (dox4j doesn't seems to works neither).

```
final XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);
final OutputStream outPdf = new FileOutputStream("myFile.pdf");
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, outPdf, optionsPdf);
outPdf.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XDocReport doesn't support drawing. It could support it since docx->pdf is based on iText which supports draw, but it's a big task (any contribution are welcome!)

You can see [here](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/XWPFConverterPDFViaIText#limitations) limitation of XDocReport docx->pdf converter.